# Can we use variable as attribute in xsl:value-of select of an XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to take data from the following bean

```
-<GroupFooter id="None" parentValue="2" parentLabel="Campus" groupName="EXT_SCHOOL_NUMBER" totalSeats="11500" takenSeats="9461" specialNeeds="4" sectionCount="199" ethnicity4="0" ethnicity3="0" ethnicity2="0" ethnicity1="0" courseCount="65" X="0" N="9448" M="4" F="9">
```

F,M,N,X will be dynamic, there may be more genders in the above bean GroupFooter. So I will split the coma separated F,M,N,X and I want it just called like the following

```
<td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@courseCount"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@sectionCount"/></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@totalSeats"/></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@takenSeats"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@ethnicity1"/></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@ethnicity2"/></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@ethnicity3"/></td>
            <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@ethnicity4"/></td>
            <xsl:if test="/ReportMax/META_NODE/@COLS='17'">
                <td class="txtsmall3" style="text-align: center; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin;"><xsl:value-of select="@specialNeeds"/></td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'F,M,N,X,'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
```

This is the template that I am using

```
<xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
   <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'F,M,N,X,'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

And it is defined as following

```
<xsl:template name="SimpleStringLoop">
 <xsl:param name="input"/>
 <xsl:if test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
   <xsl:variable name="v" select="substring-before($input, ',')"/>
   <td class="txtsmall3"><xsl:value-of select="@$v"/></td>
   <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ',')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to make $v point to the attribute, can anyone please help.

Comment: Which "attribute" do you want to "point" a variable reference to? Perhaps show us the result you want to create for the sample code you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of `<xsl:value-of select="@$v"/>` you want `<xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name() = $v]"/>`. Make sure the context node is the element having the attributes.